# Any restriction To add dependency in gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies

I have just started `Android Studio` from last 1 months. Its nice to work and more functionality with gradle.

But i have one question.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'


    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
}
```

In `App gradle` we add dependency one bye one.
So my question is the Is there any restriction to add dependency in `build.gradle` file ?

Maximum how much we can add. If we add much dependency then will it throw error

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed:
Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

Advance help would be appriciated !!

Comment: There is no limit. But you should care about `65K reference limit` and for that you need `Multidex build support`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

build.gradle
We can add any number of dependency, There is no  such limit.

Limit is building Apps with Over 65K Methods. Refer [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)

Answer (score 0):

No there is no limit but you have to take care of these things.

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html
http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

you have to read this doc it will improve our app

> When your application and the libraries it references reach a certain size, you encounter build errors that indicate your app has reached a limit of the Android app build architecture. Earlier versions of the build system report this error as follows:

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed:
Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

> But now you can use multidex

Comment: Aashvi amdavad ni che to gujarati chat room ma avi jao android mate !

Comment: @PiyushGupta Mujhe gujrati nhi aati